# Wait the StartCoroutine to be finish before execute the next line of code without Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lambda

```
public bool  Login(string LoginName,string username,string password)
    {
        RequestHeader contentTypeHeader = new RequestHeader
        {
            Key = "Content-Type",
            Value = "application/json"
        };
        JsonData data = new JsonData();
        data["username"] = username;
        data["password"] = password;
       StartCoroutine(NetworkManage.Instance.HttpPost(tempapiConfig[LoginName], data.ToJson(), (r) =>
       {
           testing = OnRequestLoginComplete(r);
           Debug.Log(testing);
       }, new List<RequestHeader>
        {
            contentTypeHeader
        }));

   return testing;
}
 bool OnRequestLoginComplete(Response response)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Status Code: {response.StatusCode}");
        Debug.Log($"Data: {response.Data}");
        Debug.Log($"Error: {response.Error}");
        return true;
    }
 
   return testing;
```

So the problem is like as you can see I started a coroutine where the testing= the callback which return the bool.
But the login returned the testing before the coroutine is finish. So let’s say the httpost need two second before able to give the callback to testing. But the login function return testing right away without waiting which makes the returned value is the wrong one

The testing Boolean will wait for the call back, so let say I want to return the value of the testing. The login return it right away before it get hear from the callback.

Comment: Well, do whatever you need to do in `OnRequestLoginComplete` .. I guess the result is somewhere in the `response.Data` .. probably some JSON you have to deserialize?

Comment: The only way to do that would be making `Login` itself a coroutine or async ...

Comment: I will try the code tmr thanks

Comment: Edited again but I will test it tmr

Answer (score 0):

Your way is a bit unconventional, there is no need to return true/false when the response is the state of the request:

```
    public IEnumerator Login(string LoginName,string username,string password, Action<string> jsonResponse)
    {
        RequestHeader contentTypeHeader = new RequestHeader
        {
            Key = "Content-Type",
            Value = "application/json"
        };
        JsonData data = new JsonData();
        data["username"] = username;
        data["password"] = password;
        yield return StartCoroutine(NetworkManage.Instance.HttpPost(tempapiConfig[LoginName],
          data.ToJson(), 
          (r) =>
          {
              jsonResponse?.Invoke(r);
          }, new List<RequestHeader>
          {
              contentTypeHeader
          }));
  }
```

And this could be used as such:

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    string response = null;
    yield return StartCoroutine(Login(loginname,username, pwd, 
        (r) => response = r));
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(response)){
       Debug.LogError("No response");
    }
    ResponseType rt = JsonUtility.FromJson<ResponseType>(response);
}
```

Comment: `Your way is a bit unconventional` .. In wouldn't say that .. it is **impossible** without either freezing the execution or making `Login` itself either a coroutine or async. Using a callback is THE way to go if you don't want to do that for some reason

Comment: Btw instead of `yield return StartCoroutine(Login(...));` you can also directly `yield return Login(...);`

Comment: I edited but will have a look tmr